# Request-promise API call not updating variable as expected in React app

Tags: javascript, request-promise

I have the following IIFE in a React app:

```
const GetFeedData = (function () {
    let feed, feedId;
    return {
        getFeedId: function (sub) {
            switch (sub) {
                case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case 'S':
                    feedId = 1;
                    break;
                case 'A': case 'C': case 'E':
                    feedId = 26;
                    break;
                case 'N': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'W':
                    feedId = 16;
                    break;
                case 'B': case 'D': case 'F': case 'M':
                    feedId = 21;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    feedId = 2;
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    feedId = 31;
                    break;
            }
        },
        getFeedData: function () {
            rp({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=MY_KEY&feed_id=' + feedId,
                encoding: null
            }).then((buf) => {
                feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(buf);
            });
        },
        get feed() { return feed; }
    };
})();
```

As you can see, `getFeedData` should be updating the `feed` variable, which will later be called as a property on `GetFeedData`. Right now, when that variable is called later in my code, it's coming up as `undefined` and causing the rest of the script to fail.

I substituted in the following code for `getFeedData` to test whether that would affect the outcome:

```
getFeedData: function () {
        if (feedId === 2) {
            feed = require('./MockData');
        }
```

When I passed in `'L'` as the `sub` parameter, getting the condition in `getFeedData` to return `true` (a process which happens using a dropdown menu in one of my components), I was no longer getting the TypeError saying that `feed` was undefined. I'm assuming that means my problem is in the API call? Can anyone tell me if that sounds correct and what I might do to fix the issue?

Comment: your `getFeedData` function fails to return a thing

Comment: I think the reason why it's coming up undefined it's because it's an async request and you are called the variable `feed` before `getFeedData` had time to assign its value. Try to put a `console.log(buf)` or `alert(buf)` in your method to test whether that hypothesis is true or not.

Comment: `get feed() { return feed; }` won't wait for a promise to resolve

Comment: @FrenchMajesty Yeah that does seem to be the issue. Any idea how I fix it? I'm assuming that making `getFeedData` synchronous would be a bad idea, but I'm a little lost otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a direct reference to a variable who's value is being set by an asynchronous function because you will run into inconsistencies where the value is returned `undefined`.

However, you can directly return the `feed` variable from `getFeedData` method via a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
const GetFeedData = (function() {

    // more code here...

    return {
        GetFeedData: () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                rp({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=MY_KEY&feed_id=' + feedId,
                    encoding: null
                }).then((buf) => {
                    feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(buf);
                    resolve(feed)
                }).catch(_ => reject())
            })
        },
    }
})()

// Use it like this
GetFeedData.GetFeedData().then((feed) => {
    console.log(feed)
})
```